# Jenkins blueocean beta not available

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to install the blueocean beta plugin for my Jenkins server.

The first thing I saw is that I was not getting the proper plugins so I have updated my plugin url to:

```
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/experimental/update-center.json
```

Currently did a clean install without any other plugins, maybe there are some other plugins that are required for the blueocean plugin?

I am using version 2.19.4, so far my experience with Jenkins has been terrible and there does not seem to be a proper support forum so I am asking here.

Hopefully somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the update (http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json), restarted Jenkins (v2.19.4) so "Blue Ocean Beta" showed up at Manage Plugins > Available and I was able to install.